# Renaming maven's settings.xml fixed missed dependency errors?

Tags: java, maven

I was recently getting build failures within maven saying that I had missing dependencies that should have easily been picked up. I tried just about everything, and the only thing that seemed to work was renamed my maven's settings.xml to settings1.xml? If I change that file back to the original name it misses all of my .jars that should be seen. What is going on here? Is there another settings file that it is using?

Comment: what IDE You are using?

Comment: You should include the contents of your settings.xml file in the question. As it stands now one can only *guess* as to what the actual issue may be.

Comment: Maven using the wrong settings.xml can be a royal pita. Where is yours located?

Comment: Eclipse, using the m2e connector. My initial scare. Mine is located on the C:\Development folder I created in the apache-maven-3.0.4 folder that came from the initial download. "C:\Development\apache-maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml"

Comment: I do have a maven 2.2.1 in the same Development folder, but I have checked the mvn --version from command line and it is definitely using 3.0.4.

Comment: Now check if under C:\Users\[Your user]\.m2 available settings.xml?

Comment: Nope, no settings.xml in .m2

Comment: What would specifically help within the settings.xml to see?

Comment: I guess your m2e connector has to override your settings.xml with default settings if it hasn't found configuration file.

Comment: Do I need to point directly to that settings.xml file somehow?

Comment: I don't know, but You can provide right repositories in your real settings.xml, to download the jars from right places